# Maintain multiple versions of an API Rest

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, rest, architecture

I have a API Rest made with Express, this is consumed by a iOS client. sometimes I have to make changes to some endpoints (Breaking Changes), I'll release a new built of the iOS App but may happens not all users update the client event if the client is running the application and I deploy the new backend version.

1. How to maintain multiple versions of the backend?
2. What is a good way to do this without have complex rules in the code
3. In case that I execute different multiples instances of the base and response to each client with the correct version, now to deal with the database?

How @MikeBrant propouse I'll reduce the scope

I'm using

- Node
- Express
- Postgres

I'm not using a framework like sailjs or loopback

Comment: This is much too broad of a question to answer here, as there are any number of ways one might approach providing versioned API endpoints and the applicability of these approaches may change based on what sort of framework (if any) you are using.  Also, in some cases, you might want to set up entirely different sets of infrastructure to handle different API versions depending on the needs of the application and nature of changes between revisions.

Comment: @MikeBrant can you give a some advice how to reduce the scope

Comment: There is not really a good way to reduce the scope of this question.  One would have to be familiar with your application logic, the data store, the routing mechanism, etc. to think about how to best provide API versioning for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, REST is for consuming resources and one could
argue that you use it precisely to decouple it from backend implementation
(which means it doesnt care which database, framework, ... you use).

Second, if you realy have complete implementation for first version, then
it should be frozen, which in regard means don't touch backend implementation
for that versin, copy routes and change them accordingly.

IMHO (what i would do):

1. Write test for first version so you don't break something (mandatory)
2. Prefix your urls with REST version (like everyone else, nothing new here), e.g.: api/v1/... or something like that
3. Since you are using express you can always prefix your routes with some variable, lets say apiPath ('api/v1' for first, 'api/v2'), so you end up with something like app.delete(apiPath + '/photos/:id')

Now this is where it starts to get tricky and thats domain of your problem.
If it's only model domain (new data that can be saved/retrieved) than this is easy. Suplement models with getters/setters that use attributes depending on 
API version. 
Lets say you use moongose: 
`

```
userSchema.virtual('v1_properties').get(function() {
    return ['email', 'name'];
});
userSchema.virtual('v2_properties').get(function() {
    return ['email', 'name', 'surname'];
});
modelSchema.virtual('attributes').get(function() {
    // atributes that are prefixed with api version
    var self = this;
    var json = {};
    self[apiVersion + '_properties'].foreach(function(key) {
        json[key] = self[key];
    });

    return json;
});
```

`
For setters you do same thing. **Of course** it's a bad idea to couple
API version with models, this is only for example purposes.

Unfortunately, this doesn't fix problem if you changed specific business logic. Remember, there is deprecation for a reason. 
If your changes realy broke something in older API then i presume there
are only 2 options, deprecation of first API or migration of data when 
users do finaly update their apps.
In case they use different app versions for same account this still means that 
for them old API is practicaly deprecated.

I hope this was useful to you in some way. Let me know if you have more 
questions or if you can specify your problem in more detail and I will try
to update answer.
`

Answer (score 0):

Mike is correct, it's difficult to say what the best solution for your particular API may be. However, to provide you with a possible solution, here is a very simple way to maintain different API versions.  Of course this is based on a lot of assumptions and may not be the best or cleanest solution for your API.

For simple APIs you can maintain different versions by defining a Constant in your app. This constant will be the path to the root of your API endpoint.  Typically this would carry the same name as your app's version, like "myApp/v1-8-5/" assuming your app version was 1.8.5.  Server side, you would maintain a directory for each version of your app that would contain the complete API.  Every new release of your app, you would update the Constant and add the new directory to your endpoint.

This is not the most elegant solution and as stated before, it may not be the best solution for your needs but it is a solution....

Comment: Assuming this solution, How to deal with the database?

Comment: If you're changing your database structure, then all bets are off. If the structure is not changing and you are simply adding to it, then the code in your API should address the changes. Also, just want to state again that this may not be the best solution for your API, much more detail would be needed to give you a specific answer for your API.